# Dockable div wih css

Tags: css, html, dock

I need to have a div, docked to right, with fixed horizontal size.
I dont know how to set a correct position for it.
his left coord must be smth SCREENWIDTH - 500.
I see only left positioning with position absolute.
This is really not what i want.

Comment: My question is how to write css for such div

Comment: "You need to" post your sample of code so we can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

use `right:0`

```
.right {
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
}
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8KXtG/)